# numpy.load retrieves savez'ed arrays in the wrong order

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.5

I am using numpy arrays that I store in a list. These arrays have no individual names, and I just call them by their index in the list.

I need to save and retrieve them all together, hence I used `numpy.savez` to store them into a single file. As my arrays are unnamed I just enumerated the list, and `numpy.savez` assigned them automatic names "arr_0", "arr_1", and so on.

But when I attempted to retrieve them all using `numpy.load` I discovered that `numpy.load` lists the arrays in a seemingly random order. Of course I can sort this list before restoring my arrays, but I find it quite strange that there is no straightforward way to store and retrieve an ordered list of unnamed arrays.

Here is a piece of test code to demonstrate the thing:

```
import numpy as np

arr_list = []
for i in range(15):
    arr_list.append(np.array(range(i, i+6)).reshape(2, 3))

np.savez('testfile', *arr_list)
with np.load('testfile.npz') as data:
    print(data.files)
```

And here is what I get:

```
>>> ['arr_1', 'arr_3', 'arr_13', 'arr_11', 'arr_14', 'arr_10', 'arr_8', 'arr_0', 
     'arr_2', 'arr_9', 'arr_5', 'arr_4', 'arr_6', 'arr_12', 'arr_7']
```

What's more, I never get twice the same result. Next try:

```
>>> ['arr_6', 'arr_11', 'arr_10', 'arr_13', 'arr_0', 'arr_7', 'arr_5', 'arr_3', 
     'arr_14', 'arr_2', 'arr_8', 'arr_12', 'arr_1', 'arr_9', 'arr_4']
```

Unfortunately I cannot just sort the list using `sorted()`, as the result is not what I need (and this is why I gave an example with more than 10 items in the list):

```
>>> ['arr_0', 'arr_1', 'arr_10', 'arr_11', 'arr_12', 'arr_13', 'arr_14', 'arr_2', 
     'arr_3', 'arr_4', 'arr_5', 'arr_6', 'arr_7', 'arr_8', 'arr_9']
```

I can't figure out why `numpy.savez` + `numpy.load` gives such a strange behaviour. Did I miss something, or do I definitely have to use a regex to sort this out?

Comment: `data` is a dictionary like object, allowing access to individual arrays via `data['arr_0']`.  The keys of a dictionary are unordered.

Comment: @hpaulj: While `data` is dictionary-like, `data.files` is not.

Comment: Perhaps intentionally, the `savez` docs examples show the variable names shuffled.  The intent is that arrays will be returned by name rather than by list order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the implementation of `savez` in numpy. Looking at the [source code of savez](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ae842001332f532e0c76815d49336ecc2b88dde/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L637) we see that the list of arrays to be saved (contained in the `args` argument) is added to a dictionary containing arrays to be stored (the `kwargs` argument). The order of the arrays in the `args` list may be lost at this stage (depending on the Python version that is used).

Since you know the format of the filenames you can either sort them

```
sorted_files = sorted(data.files, key=lambda x:int(x[4:]))
```

or recreate the list

```
sorted_files = ['arr_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(data.files))]
```

Comment: So the order from `load` is the same as I get from `unzip -l`.

Comment: The docs do not guarantee this. `data.files` is obtained by calling [`ZipFile.namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) which mentions nothing about the order of file names, unlike [`ZipFile.infolist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist). It is likely that this is an unintentional omission, but nevertheless not something you can rely on.

Comment: @pafcu: Thanks for your explanation, and I will sort my list using your first suggestion. As for your second suggestion, I'm afraid it misses the point as it just creates a new ordered list of names, but does not help me to sort out my data files. Anyway I can't help thinking that there should exist a simple and straightforward mechanism to store and retrieve an ordered list of arrays. I can't believe I am the first one to need this...

Comment: If you save your arrays by passing them as a list then the second method will result in exactly the same list as `data.files` sorted according to the first method. It's just a list of strings. Why do you need them sorted?

Comment: I thought I was not supposed to pass a `list` to `savez`, only a series of args each representing one array. This is why I wanted to retrieve them in the same order, as it was the only way for me to put the retrieved data in the right place. And unlike the example in my question above, my actual arrays all differ in shapes from each other. Hence passing a `list` to `savez` will generate a multiarray, although it would generate a normal `numpy.ndarray` with one more dimension if my arrays happened to all have the same shapes. Different file formats depending on the contents, I don't like this.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is to use pickle. `savez` is basically intended to save a bunch of loosely related data, while you actually specifically want to save a single ordered list of arrays. It's simply a convenience function that is not intended for your use case (and, thus, is not very convenient).